# Spring FTP Integration : Very slow when remote directory is having 5000000 files

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using flowing code. Remote directory is having more than 5000000 files (I know it is bad). I am looking to get only one file from there (myFile.txt) and same file updated on a non-fixed interval and then I have to get it again. Spring FTP integration is working like charm but it always take almost 10-12 minutes to transfer myFile.txt after update. myFile.txt is not a big file (approx 800 KB). It seems spring FTP API first execute listFiles() and then filter out for my specific file ( may be I am wrong). Is any thing wrong in my code due to that file FTP is slow?

```
@Bean
@Lazy(false)
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(server);
    sf.setPort(port);
    sf.setUsername(username);
    sf.setPassword(password);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
}

@Bean
public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());

    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);

    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("myFile.txt")));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}



@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1") )
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(localFtpDirectory));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageHandler ftpHandler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            LOG.info("File '{}' is ready for reading after FTP", message.getPayload());
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it lists all files; you will probably have better performance if you use the outbound gateway to GET the single file you want, without listing them all first.

See [FTP outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway).